# URL open new window adjust size

Tags: javascript, url, popup

I am using a map on my website. When you click a link on the map it opens a new window. The rest of the site uses colorbox to open new links so in a desire to keep it close to that in appearance, I would like the new window that opens to be more like a popup not like a new tab. Currently I just have this:

url_new_tab: 'yes',

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

colorbox is good idea.

otherwise you may use

```
window.open('your_url', '_blank', 'width=600, height=300');
```

Comment: There are a variety of other options beyond width and height that can be set, as well. Examples here: http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

Comment: window.open('your_url', '_blank', 'width=600, height=300'); is working except now it pops up automatically when you open the page, how do I make it happen only on click??

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out for anyone having the same issue:

url: "javascript:'onclick'=window.open('url_here', '_blank','width=800, height=500');",